# How to bind variables to Closure?

Tags: php

I am looking how to implement a function, that binds any variable to function.

Using **hypothetical** function `\Closure::bindVariable($closure, $name, $value)`, implementation could be like this:

```
function bindAnything($closure, $anyVariables)
{
     foreach ($variables as $variable => $value) {
         \Closure::bindVariable($closure, $variable, $value);
     }
     return $variable;
}
```

Unfortunatelly, there is no `\Closure::bindVaraiable`. There is `\Closure::bind`, but only `$this` is bound by this function.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

---

*UPDATE*: It seems there is no way how to easily do this. What about some generating code & eval magic?

Comment: I don't think this is possible but I also can't think of any good use for such a feature.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php ?

Comment: And what would you do with it?

Comment: Will bind closure to object with new scope and it variables. $someobj = (object)("variable"->"bar"); $cl->bindTo($someobj);

Comment: @AlexanderShcheglakov - No, this binds only $this, not any variable

Comment: @fschmengler Understand your curiosity. When creating highly dynamic system this would solve some problem I have there. But it can (and will be solved differently)

Comment: @jasir Could you please be a bit more specific about what you need? Do you want a closure with some arguments pre-bound? Like the Closure expects 4 args, you bind two params to it and then have the caller pass the other two args?

Comment: A potential usage of this is to wrap array_map and array_reduce into a higher-level function that receives a callback, binds the actual array and calls these. The "binds the actual array" part is what this question asks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I do not understand, but I try to answer.

As I can see from the documentation, the bind method is here, to set an object context for the closure.

So if you have object foo:

```
class foo {};
$foo = new foo();
```

You can access to `foo` by `$this` in the closure.

Maybe you want to have something like that:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->bar = "42";

$closure = function() {
    return $this->bar;
};

$closure.bindTo($foo);
echo $closure();
```

Maybe you want this:

```
function bindAnything($closure, $anyVariables)
{
    $obj = (object)$anyVariables;
    $closure.bindTo($obj);
    return $closure;
}

$closure = function() {
    return $this->foo;
};

var $arr = ["foo" => "bar"];

$newClosure = bindAnything($closure, $arr);
echo $newClosure();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have searched for a way how to bind any variable, not just $this. Eg. function (myfunc) use ($a, $b) {...} - $a and $b are bind by syntax feature of php, I am searching for a way how to do this programatically

Comment: What are you trying to do? A parameterizes Closure would not work for you?

Comment: Original motivation was probably a over-engineered solution, now I would say this question is more about curiosity what is possible in php.

Comment: The `bindTo` method is for binding the closure to an object. The current object is always accessed by `$this` from a method. The object you are binding can have as much fields or properties you want. Here we have also magic `__get` and `__set` method. I think you are mixing here something. I don't think you are looking for binding an object. I think you are looking at this: [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

Comment: But maybe some more context on what you are trying to would help to find a good way/solution to this.